# how to add an intermediate calculated "variable" in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

I am an Informatica newbie, and making a flow like:

```
(Source A - Source A Qualifier) and (Source B - Source B Qualifier) -> Joiner -> Target
```

say I need to calculate a a variable/column over Source A in order to join Source A and Source B.

Can you please help me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Expression transformation to calculate the value required. This would be placed between Source A and the joiner, with an output only port added with the logic inside.

However, if the calculation is simple enough, you can have it pre-computed in the SQL query for Source A. This is advantageous as it will allow you to sort both sources on the common column(s) and use the Sorted Input option on the Joiner, which performs much better.

Comment: thanks a lot ! I have another quick question... how can I get the informatica syntax knowledge? I was trying to find it in their site but couldn't find any suitable guide for that.

Comment: The PowerCenter Help menu is excellent, and has all the information you'll ever need. I don't blame you for not trying that already, as Help functions are almost always terrible!